# How to generate a memory heap dump from a running C# mono application?

Tags: c#, mono, heap-memory

I have a Mono application running under `Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1)` with `--debug` enabled. After quiet some time, I get quiet unexpected memory usage.

I know there is [HeapShot](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/heapshot/) but it generates over 4GB of output even before the problem gets real. In addition the UI tool can not load more than ~17 of the included Snapshots before running out of memory while loading the Dump.

That's why I'm looking for a way to produce a single Heap dump of my application when the memory usage grew big. Is there any way?

An alternative would be to get better tooling to load single snapshots from a huge generated HeapShot dump.

Any hints how to find the memory leak would be helpful, too.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm only using Mono 4.6 and above, I can not remember if 3.2.x supports `heapshot=` (I think it does...) so you can control when to sample, either based on GC collects,`XXgc` or time based, `XXXXms`. Also I never use the "GUI" tool, just the cmd line `mprof-report`. Also make sure you are limiting the profile to just heap shots to help reduce report size (along with using heapshot=XXXX), `log:headshot`

Comment: I got a heapshot `Heap shot 21 at 6155.078 secs` but `mprof-report --time=6100-6200 output.mlpd` returns all heapshots. When I add `--traces --maxframes=2` my memory usage explodes .. any ideas? I just need to get information about the last heap shot #21

Comment: And I can not find mpfrof-report on my windows mono installation. Google does not help. Any hints here?

Answer (score 2):

run in first terminal, it will not produce dump until command "heapshot" sent

```
mono --debug --profile=log:heapshot,heapshot=ondemand,time=fast,port=7103,output=%p.mlpd MyApp.exe
```

to obtain heapshot ondemand run in second terminal to send command "heapshot"

```
echo -n "heapshot\n" | nc localhost 7103
```

You need to install netcat package from your distro